# How to get max value from cassandra table with where clause

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I have a little design problem, I have the following request:

```
SELECT MAX(idt) FROM table WHERE idt < 2018
```

but I can't figure out how to create the table according to this request.
*idt* must be a clustering key to be able to *do greater than* or *lower than* operations as well as the max aggragation but I don't know what should I use as partition key (I don't want to use ALLOW FILTERING).
The only solution I've found is to use a constant value as partition key but I know it's considered as a bad design.
Any help?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you want to achieve - please describe problem that you want to solve...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to partition your data somehow. If you do not it will be like you say, is to either read everything from whole cluster (allow filtering) or put everything in a single partition (constant key). Not knowing anything about your data, design or goals, a common setup is to partition by date like:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE bucket = '2018' AND id < 100 limit 1;
```

Then your key would look like `((bucket), id)` ordering id DESC so largest at head of partition. In this case buckets are by year so end up making a query per year that your looking for. if idt is not unique you might need to do something like:

`((uuid), idt)` or `((bucket), uuid, idt)` sorting by idt DESC (once again issues if not unique for that record). Then you can do things like

```
SELECT max(idt) FROM table WHERE GROUP BY bucket
```

although still better to

```
SELECT max(idt) FROM table WHERE bucket = '2018' GROUP BY bucket
```

which will give you the max per bucket so you would have to page through it and generate the global max yourself, but it is better for cluster as it will naturally throttle a little vs single query slamming whole cluster. Might be good idea on that query to also limit the fetch size to like 10 or 100 or something vs the default 5000, so the resultset pages slower (preventing too much work on coordinator).

To have the work to do all this done somewhere else you might wanna consider Spark, as it can give you a lot more rich queries and do it as efficiently as it can (which might not be efficient but it will try).